# Xamarin.Forms : UI is not rendering for the same way on iOS 10.1 and iOS 10.4

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin.forms, navigationbar

I work on a **Xamarin.Forms app** where I need to implement **transparent/translucent navigation bar**.

I've studied the the **Vision Conference** [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/ConferenceVision), where this is implemented.

This is achieved through a `CustomNavigationPage` and a `CustomRenderer`.

The **XAML** of the `CustomNavigationPage` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NavigationPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="ConferenceVision.Views.CustomNavigationPage"
    xmlns:iOS="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    iOS:NavigationPage.IsNavigationBarTranslucent="True"
    BarTextColor="{StaticResource NavigationBarTextColor}">
    <NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
            <On Platform="Android, iOS" Value="Transparent" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="{StaticResource NavigationBarBackgroundColor}" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor>
</NavigationPage>
```

The **code-behind** of the `CustomNavigationPage` is:

```
public partial class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public bool IgnoreLayoutChange { get; set; } = false;

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        if (!IgnoreLayoutChange)
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    }

    public CustomNavigationPage() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CustomNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the `CustomRenderer` is:

```
public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = true;
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
        {
            Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue-Light", (nfloat)20f),
            TextColor = UIColor.White
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I've tested the app on :

- simulators : **iPhone 6** on **iOS 11.3**
- my device : **iPhone 6** on **iOS 10.1**

And we can see that the **results are not the same**. On the simulator and **iOS 11.3**, there is a gap between the navigation bar and the content:

[image: screenshot iOS 11.3]

But on my device under **iOS 10.1**, there is no gap and the content is displayed "under" the navigation bar:

[image: screenshot iOS 10.1]

The page is built like that, but the rendering is the same on all pages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:ConferenceVision.Effects"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConferenceVision.Views.Renderers"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"              
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             Title="About"
             x:Class="ConferenceVision.Views.AboutView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <ScrollView>
                <ScrollView.Margin>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Default="15,0">
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="15,50,15,0"/>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </ScrollView.Margin>
                ...
            </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

***How explain it? Could this be related to the use of `UseSafeArea`?
I know that I get an "old" version on my device, but in my app I have to cover the largest number of users.***

Answer (score 0):

The difference between iOS is related to the use of SafeArea. In iOS 11+ the safearea adds a paddind.

`ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"`

Comment: So it's was what I thought. But what is the better way to fix it? Remove the `UseSafeArea` and manage padding manually? Or keep it, and manage padding for "older" iOS versions?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for that version. You must always use the last 3 version of each mobile OS, because their marketshare grants you a better stability, compatibility and acceptance with the public.

This are the numbers for the 10.1 in the world (from [NetMarketshare](https://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?options=%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22%24and%22%3A%5B%7B%22deviceType%22%3A%7B%22%24in%22%3A%5B%22Mobile%22%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22dateLabel%22%3A%22Trend%22%2C%22attributes%22%3A%22share%22%2C%22group%22%3A%22platformVersion%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22share%22%3A-1%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%22platformsMobileVersions%22%2C%22dateInterval%22%3A%22Monthly%22%2C%22dateStart%22%3A%222017-07%22%2C%22dateEnd%22%3A%222018-06%22%2C%22plotKeys%22%3A%5B%7B%22platformVersion%22%3A%22iOS%2010.1%22%7D%2C%7B%22platformVersion%22%3A%22iOS%2010.2%22%7D%2C%7B%22platformVersion%22%3A%22iOS%2010.3%22%7D%2C%7B%22platformVersion%22%3A%22iOS%2011.3%22%7D%2C%7B%22platformVersion%22%3A%22iOS%2011.2%22%7D%2C%7B%22platformVersion%22%3A%22iOS%2011.0%22%7D%2C%7B%22platformVersion%22%3A%22iOS%2011.1%22%7D%5D%2C%22pageLength%22%3A50%2C%22segments%22%3A%22-1000%22%7D))

[image]

Just tell the users to use a more updated version.

Comment: Hi @Diomendes thanks again for your feedback. I will ingore this issue as the iOS 10.x part is no longer important.